# I want to transform a list or concatenate this same list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list like here that I coded in python

```
li = []                                                                  
for x in T:
   li.append(x.split())                                            
print(li)
```

```
[['pts', 'J.', 'G.', 'N.', 'P.', 'p.', 'c.', '+/-', 'G.', 'N.', 'P.'],
 ['1', 'Paris-SG', '45', '18', '14', '3', '1', '38', '16', '+22'],
 ['2', 'Marseille'],
 ['32', '17', '9', '5', '3', '25', '14', '+11'],
 ['3', 'Rennes'],
 ['31', '18', '9', '4', '5', '33', '16', '+17'],
 ['4', 'Nice', '30', '18', '9', '4', '5', '27', '16', '+11'],
 ['5', 'Montpellier'],
 ['28', '18', '8', '4', '6', '29', '23', '+6'],
 ['6', 'Lens'],
 ['27', '18', '7', '6', '5', '32', '26', '+6'],
 ['7', 'Strasbourg'],
 ['26', '18', '7', '5', '6', '34', '24', '+10'],
 ['8', 'Monaco'],
 ['26', '18', '7', '5', '6', '27', '22', '+5']]
```

and I would like to transform it to be able to integrate it into a dataframe more easily

```
[['pts', 'J.', 'G.', 'N.', 'P.', 'p.', 'c.', '+/-', 'G.', 'N.', 'P.'],
 ['1', 'Paris-SG', '45', '18', '14', '3', '1', '38', '16', '+22'],
 ['2', 'Marseille','32', '17', '9', '5', '3', '25', '14', '+11'],
 ['3', 'Rennes', '31', '18', '9', '4', '5', '33', '16', '+17'],
 ['4', 'Nice', '30', '18', '9', '4', '5', '27', '16', '+11'],
 ['5', 'Montpellier', '28', '18', '8', '4', '6', '29', '23', '+6'],
 ['6', 'Lens','27', '18', '7', '6', '5', '32', '26', '+6'],
 ['7', 'Strasbourg', '26', '18', '7', '5', '6', '34', '24', '+10'],
 ['8', 'Monaco', '26', '18', '7', '5', '6', '27', '22', '+5']]
```

Comment: How did it get to be that way?  If this is from embedded newlines, it would be easier to patch it while you are creating the list.

Comment: Your first code sample may be better as: `li = [x.split() for x in T]`.

Comment: I don't have the good practice yet, thank you for this idea

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the bad lines always have 8 elements:

```
li = []                                                                  
for x in T:
    p = x.split()
    if len(p) == 8:
        li[-1].extend(p)
    else:
        li.append(p)
print(li)
```

Alternatively, I suppose you could use:

```
    if p[1].isdigit():
```

Answer (score 0):

So we have your original data as `data`.

Obviously we don't touch the first line.

```
first_line = data[0]
```

The remaining data can be accessed as `data[1:]`. We need to split out the correct and incorrect lines. We can write a function `part` that will do this.

```
def part(pred, lst):
    t, f = [], []
    for x in lst:
        (t if pred(x) else f).append(x)
    return (t, f)
```

Now we can create variable names for these.

```
correct, incorrect = part(lambda x: len(x) == 10, data[1:])
```

Now we define another very simple function that will put the incorrect data lines into pairs.

```
def pairs(lst):
    for i in range(0, len(lst) - 1, 2):
        yield (lst[i], lst[i + 1])
```

The rest can essentially be a single line.

```
[first_line] + correct + [x + y for x, y in pairs(incorrect)]
```

But it looks like you want the cities sorted.

```
corrected_lines = correct + [x + y for x, y in pairs(incorrect)]

[first_line] + list(sorted(corrected_lines, key=lambda a: a[0]))
```